# Java Recursion Expression Checker

Tags: java, recursion

Design the function to input a string and output 'true' or 'false' - telling whether or not the string is an expression.

Print a message telling whether the string is a well-formed expression. Finally, after processing all the input, the program prints an exit message and stops. 
 The following rule defines a well-formed expression:

```
.expr> = S | I(C)T(.exp>)
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RecursionExpression {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        System.out.println("Enter the expression statement.");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String expr = keyboard.nextLine();
    }
    public static boolean expression(String n)
    {
        if (n.charAt(0) == 's')
        return true;
        else if(n.length() >=6)
        {
            if (n.substring(0,5) == "I(C)T")
                return expression(n.substring(6, n.length()-1));


        }
        return false;

    }
}
```

Comment: Basically you dropped your assignment here; and telling us that you cant solve it. But what is your question? That we do your homework for you? If you don't understand how to interpret that expr definition; did you consider asking your teacher for clarification?

Comment: Whoops sorry i did not put in the right code. Will update right now.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the condition that the first character is `'s'` is insufficient (and according to the rule it should be an uppercase `'S'` BTW). This can even throw an exception for empty strings. Furthermore it accepts *any* string starting with an `s`, including `"so you want this string to match too"`.

Furthermore you do not check for the `()` brackets around `.exp>`, which also needs to be done. Furthermore comparing `String`s that are not compile time constants with `==` does not work (see [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) ):

```
public static boolean expression(String n) {
    return n.equals("S") ||
            (n.startsWith("I(C)T(") && n.endsWith(")") && expression(n.substring(6, n.length()-1)));
}
```